# Função mail() do php não está funcionando

Tags: php, email

Estou utilizando a função `mail()` do PHP para tentar enviar alguns dados que são informados em meu formulário; a função está retornando `true` só que nunca chega o email para o destinatário. Abaixo está o código PHP:

```
$headers = 'From: ServidorCafé <contato@servidorcafedigital.com.br>'."\r\n" .
        'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n".
        "Return-Path: contato <contato@servidorcafedigital.com.br>\r\n".
        'Content-type: text/html; charset=UTF-8' . "\r\n";


        $envia = mail('alissonacioli@hotmail.com', 'Pesquisa preenchida', $corpo, $headers);

        if($envia){

            echo '<div align="center" style="height:30px;width:100%; background-color:green; color:#fff; font-size:13px; font-family:Verdana">Mensagem enviada com sucesso!</div>';
        }
```

em **$corpo** é o formulário HTML que fiz com `<table>`

Comment: Ja viu a caixa de spam? Se o destinatario for hotmail, todo envio de email pela funcao mail ira para o Spam. Mude para um destinatario gmail. Veja a versao do PHP do seu servidor se é 5. Obs:  use SMTP

Comment: Não está no spam. A versão é 5 do PHP.

Comment: Espera. Vou te mandar um código.

Comment: Tente retirar o acento no ServidorCafé. Já tive problemas com caracteres especiais no envio de email.

Comment: @AlissonAcioli Por que a função `mail` retornou `TRUE` não significa que o e-mail chegou ao destinatário, só significa que chegou ao "serviço de email" do seu servidor e provavelmente entrou na fila (me corrijam se eu estiver errado). Existe a probabilidade de estar com um problema no seu SMTP, ou no hotmail o "IP do seu servidor" estar bloqueado (é só teoria). Já pensou em usar uma SMTP ao invés de `mail`? Muitos desenvolvedores passam por estas dificuldades com a função `mail`.

Comment: Onde vc esta testando? Local? Servidor? Onde esta hospedado?

Answer (score 1):

@Alisson, consegui resolver esse problema com a class phpmailer, ela permite e bem simples de usar e só precisa de php5+.

aqui tem um exemplo de como usar: http://blog.thiagobelem.net/enviar-e-mails-pelo-php-usando-o-phpmailer/

aqui tem as dúvidas frequentes do stackoverflow que podem resolver estas questôes:
https://pt.stackoverflow.com/search?q=phpmailer

O método de envio do phpmailer é largamente recomendado e é bem melhor do que o envio do mail() que á função padrão do PHP.